# Setting a default umask permanently

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

If we create a shared directory, and allow say a root user and a group sharedgroup to the permissions: `-rwxrwxr--`, and  we want every new file to have the permissions `-rwxrwxr--`, but the permission of the parent directory to be `rwxrwxr-w`. The way to do this would(what I know) be to set the default umask to 0003, but it appears once we close the terminal the umask is reset. So how do we make the change permanent **only for a directory**, because we wouldn't want to change the `umask`s of the entire system.

Comment: How are users accessing this directory? SSH into hte machine? or via a network share?

Comment: It's basically a machine, that multiple users will be logged in, like a cyber cafe where the users are given a seperate account

Comment: `r-w` for a directory makes little sense. You can't write to  a directory if you don't have search permission as you need search permissions to anything with files in the directory. Giving execute permission to every non-directory file also makes little sense. Only files meant to be executed should have that permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot customize `umask` on a per-directory basis.

The typical way to solve your particular scenario, is to use a `setfacl` default mask.